# Enum Variable and Switch Case

Tags: c, enums

I am a little confused about enums. If I declare a set of enums  `typedef enum {PLUS, MINUS, MULT, DIV} bin_op;` I get an error when assigning bin_op =  root->val in the function `float eval_arithmetic_expression` saying expected identifier or '('. Shouldn't I be allowed to assign bin_op to root->val?

```
struct BTnode {
      int value;
      struct BTnode* left;  
      struct BTnode* right;
      struct BTnode* parent;
    };
    typedef struct BTnode BTnode_t;

typedef struct BST {
  BTnode_t* root;
} BST_t;

typedef enum {PLUS, MINUS, MULT, DIV} bin_op;

float eval_arithmetic_expression(BTnode_t* root){
  bin_op = root->value;
  switch(bin_op){
    case PLUS:
       //some code
       break;
    case MINUS:
       //some code


  }
  printf("%d\n",node_val);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`typedef enum {PLUS, MINUS, MULT, DIV} bin_op;` makes `bin_op` a type, not an object with a value. So `bin_op = root->value;` attempts to assign a value, akin to writing `int = 4;`.

If you want `bin_op` to be the name of the type, leave the `typedef` and change the code in `eval_arithmetic_expression` to:

```
bin_op value = root->value;
switch (value) …
```

If you want `bin_op` to be the name of an object, change the `typedef` to either `enum foo {PLUS, MINUS, MULT, DIV};` (which makes a type called `enum foo`) or `typedef enum {PLUS, MINUS, MULT, DIV} foo;` (which makes a type called `foo`) and change the first line in `eval_arithmetic_expression` to, respectively, `enum foo bin_op;` or `foo bin_op`.